# Check multiple subdirectories using AppVeyor

Tags: r, git, github, yaml, appveyor

I have a project with multiple subdirectories which I all want to check in turn. Actually, these directories are a bit outdated version of branches which I have to keep for various reasons.

In my main folder I have the subdirectories `patch` and `pkg` and want to check both. I tried to use the following script to achieve this.

```
environment:
  matrix:
  - TEST_DIR: patch/
  - TEST_DIR: pkg/

before_build:
  - ps: echo %TEST_DIR%
  - ps: cd %TEST_DIR%

build_script:
  - travis-tool.sh install_deps
```

I also used `$TEST_DIR` and also had the lines

```
  - ps: echo %TEST_DIR%
  - ps: cd %TEST_DIR%
```

in `build_script` just before `- travis-tool.sh install_deps`. None of this was working.

When I use `echo %TEST_DIR%` it echos `%TEST_DIR%` and with `echo $TEST_DIR` nothing is echoed, i.e., the string seems to be empty. Any clues?

---

In Travis-CI I can use

```
## test multiple directories 
## (see https://lord.io/blog/2014/travis-multiple-subdirs/)
env:
 - TEST_DIR=patch/
 - TEST_DIR=pkg/

language: r
sudo: required

## change directory before installation 
## as R packages are not available elsewise
before_install:
  - cd $TEST_DIR
```

which works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [discussions](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/questions/1835-check-multiple-subdirectories) with the AppVeyor support I found a valid solution for the problem:

```
environment:
  matrix:
  - TEST_DIR: patch
  - TEST_DIR: pkg

before_build:
  - cd %TEST_DIR%
```

So, I simply needed to drop the console type (`ps` or `cmd`) to make it possible to change directories.

In my case, building and checking an R project, I additionally needed to add some lines to copy scripts etc. to my `before_build`. All together, `before_build` should thus look like:

```
before_build:
  - cp ..\travis-tool.sh .\travis-tool.sh
  - cp travis-tool.sh.cmd %TEST_DIR%\travis-tool.sh.cmd
  - cd %TEST_DIR%
  - bash -c "echo '^travis-tool\.sh\.cmd$' >> .Rbuildignore"
```

Now, AppVeyor can be used as usually with the scripts supplied by the github project [R+AppVeyor](https://github.com/krlmlr/r-appveyor).